# Perl mojolicious controllers redirecting to not_found page

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

So I am trying to return a 404 not found page in a mojolicious controller, the method is called as part of an under statement and although it temporarily redirects to the not_found page it eventually goes to the specified action and destination.

```
sub get_host_id {
my $self = shift;
my $host_id = $self->stash('host_id');
return $self->redirect_to('not_found');
return $self->render('not_found');

return $self->reply->not_found;
$self->render(text => '404 Not Found');
$self->rendered(404);
return $self->reply->not_found;
            return $self->render(
          status => 404,
          template => 'not_found',
);
                    $self->reply->not_found;
      }
              template => 'not_found',
    );
                        $self->reply->not_found;
}
```

solved:

```
  sub get_host_id {
    my $self = shift;


    return $self->redirect_to('/not_found');
        }
```

Comment: ... _how many_ `return` calls? You do realise the `sub` exits after the first one, right?

Comment: Haha yes. Sorry i went a bit wild in trying to get this to work.

Comment: [Tue Apr 11 16:11:22 2017] [debug] Rendering cached template "not_found.html.ep"
[Tue Apr 11 16:11:22 2017] [debug] 404 Not Found (0.001313s, 761.615/s)
[Tue Apr 11 16:11:22 2017] [debug] Routing to controller "Servers::Controller::Hosts" and action "get_host_id"
[Tue Apr 11 16:11:22 2017] [debug] Routing to controller "Servers::Controller::SupportTickets" and action "support_tickets"

Comment: Nevermind managed to solve it thanks to only doing one return. Thanks Sobrique

Comment: Your call `return $self->reply->not_found` should work fine if `$self` is your context object.

Comment: @dipl0: Stack Overflow isn't a chat forum. If you have a solution then you need to write it up as an answer and accept it when you are permitted. You have asked the whole world for help, and very many people will be coming to this page hoping to solve a similar problem. *"Thanks. Bye"* isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the method is called as part of an under statement

Here's the problem I think. If you redirect, you then need to return false. From [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing.pod#Under)

> The actual action code for this destination needs to return a true value or the dispatch chain will be broken

Looking at the [source code](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.33/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/DefaultHelpers.pm) for the not_found helper, the return value is always the controller object, which is true. As such, the under action will always continue to the next action regardless if a 404 has been rendered. This is not what you'd naively expect, or want.

To fix this behaviour, you will need to write something like the following in place of `return $self->reply->not_found;`

```
$self->reply->not_found and return;
```